# Downgrading Python version on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

Can someone please tell me how to downgrade Python 3.6.9 to 3.6.6 on Ubuntu ? I tried the below commands but didnot work

1) pip install python3.6==3.6.6

2) pip install python3.6.6

Comment: why don't you create a separate virtual environment?

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade a patch release?

Comment: For a project requirement that needs Python 3.6.6 and Keras 2.2.4

Comment: You can remove the package with sudo apt remove then install the 3.6 version. But may be you can use virtualenv like ahmad said it is the goal of virtualenv package

Comment: By virtual environment , do you mean using Anaconda / similar packages that allow multiple version of Python ?

Comment: @Ahmed to create a virtual environment with a specific Python version, you need to already have that version installed.

Comment: Are you sure that your package needs 3.6.6 specifically? It's unusual for packages to break on later versions of Python because Python is usually mostly backwards compatible (with the infamous exception of 3.0). It is *extremely* unusual for packages to break with minor version upgrades of Python like 3.6.6 -> 3.6.12 because minor version updates are just bug fixes, and it's normally best to have the latest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, verify that 3.6.6 is available:

```sh
apt-cache policy python3.6
```

If available:

```sh
apt-get install python3.6=3.6.6
```

If not available, you'll need to find a repo which has the version you desire and add it to your apt sources list, update, and install:

```sh
echo "<repo url>" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/python.list
apt-get update
apt-get install python3.6=3.6.6
```

I advise against downgrading your system python unless you're certain it's required. For running your application, install python3.6.6 alongside your system python, and better yet, build a virtual environment from 3.6.6:

```sh
apt-get install virtualenv
virtualenv -p <path to python3.6.6> <venv name>
```

Comment: Out of bitter experience I second that touching the system python is asking for trouble (more precisely - for system reinstall.. )

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use Anaconda, which allows you to easily use different Python versions on the same computer. [Here are the installation instructions for Anaconda on Linux](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/). Then create a Conda environment by running this command:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.6.6
```

Obviously your can use a different name than "myenv". You can then activate the environment in any terminal window:

```
conda activate myenv
```

Then you can pip install any packages you want. Some basics of anaconda environments can be found on the website's [getting started](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html) page.

Comment: how is system python different from normal python OR are both one and the same.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan "normal Python" isn't a technical term so there's no way to answer that question. But you probably mean the python you get by just typing "python3" in a terminal without doing any other setup, in which case, yes that is the system Python. The nice thing about Anaconda is that it doesn't depend on your system Python so there's no chance of it breaking your operating system (at least no more chance than any other program you install).

Comment: Thank you all for your vauable suggestions. I am going to retain my existing python and run my code